# How many ip's can i add in pfsense alias

Tags: pfsense

I have a **pfsense 2.4.4-RELEASE-p1**.I have an alias problem.

I created an alias with **~100** subnets in operator cloud,

I created a rule with this alias, but it doesn't work.

To check, I created a rule with just the desired network, and now it's OK.
So I'm wondering, is there a network limitation in an alias ?